# Rust Compiler throws error related to moving data out of a shared reference

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership

I have been writing a program in Rust where I encountered an error relating to moving the data of a Shared Reference.

I made some research, but I was unable to find the cause of the error in the program I have written. Here is the simplified version of the program:

```rust
enum A {
    Won = 1,
}

struct B {
    result: A,
}

fn print_game(game: &B) {
    println!("{}", game.result as u32);
}

fn main() {
    let game: B = B { result: A::Won };
    print_game(&game);
}
```

The above program when compiled, throws the below error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `game.result` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:10:20
   |
10 |     println!("{}", game.result as u32);
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `game.result` has type `A`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

From the error I can infer that the data in `game.result` is moved, but, I am not sure where it is moved and why it's been moved.

Comment: if I'm not mistaken this happens because to do the `i32` casting the compiler needs to take the value, hence the message that you can't move a value behind a reference, to solve it you can implement `Copy` for `A` with `#[derive(Clone, Copy)]`, like this https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f8982ec300567a4dc42be8636b0c4846

Comment: I am not assigning or returning the value in my program. Where does move happen here? @al3x

Comment: I am not completely sure but I infer from the behavior that occurs in the `T as U` cast, look at this [same playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4e140c81b9135a2db6900278d851a1f3)
 for example but just implementing `Debug` for A.



So by this I infer that casting takes the pointer by value to do its job and that is where the movement occurs.


However this is just an inference of mine, you should look for more information to corroborate if this is true or not.

Comment: A move happens when you read the value of `game.result` for whatever reason. Here you need to read it so that you can cast it to `u32` for displaying.

Comment: Note that a move occurs whenever you read _any_ value for any reason, unless the value implements `Copy` in which case the move is replaced by a copy.

Comment: @Jmb I couldn't yet grab the concept behind the statement - *move occurs whenever you read any value*.

Consider the statement - `println!("{}", game.result)`. Here 2 things happens on the outlook.

1) `game.result` is fetched (Moved as you say)
2) Passed to the println! macro which uses it's reference.

So, following by what you have said, after the `println!` statement, we cannot use `game.result` as it's moved while fetching the value right?

Comment: @PantherCoder yes, fetching a non-`Copy` value makes it unusable again.

Comment: @Jmb But, after the `println!` macro statement, I wrote another statement `let a = game.result` and it compiles successfully. No error thrown.

Comment: @PantherCoder you'll need to show the code: it fails for me ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=33a5b9048af21a5d820011136fa05352))

Comment: this does not seem correct, reading a value does not necessarily imply that the value moves, the value moves when you take it by the value itself instead of taking it by reference.  https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html

Comment: This can also be solved by cloning the `game.result` in `print_game()`: `println!("{}", game.result.clone() as u32);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rust, default behaviour for custom type is 'move' unless you implement Copy trait for the type.
If the value bound to a variable moves, the variable can not be used anymore. Developers new to Rust must get used to it.

Move is attempted in 'game.result as i32' portion of your code. Type casting is also counted as move for value of 'move' type.

I agree with the solution already mentioned above, just add the line
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f8982ec300567a4dc42be8636b0c4846)

Traits like Deref, Into, From etc. could also be relevant, but depends...

---

By 'move' compiler means just transfer of ownership, not the change of data location in memory.

Suppose we have a variable v bound to a 'move' data. In a type casting like 'v as T' the ownership of data is detached from v and the bytes are reinterpreted as type T.

But why is this casting not allowed in your example?
Actual cause of error is that 'game' is a shared reference of type &B and you tried to use it to detach original ownership of data referred by it.

> > Shared reference can never be used to move referred data or part of it. <<

Comment: Ok. So `game.result as i32` triggers the move. Can you please elaborate on how exactly does move happen here? Like, Is there any method being called while casting that tries to moves the value out of it? @mk_dhu

Comment: Original answer is extended.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think your `enum A` just needs a `#[derive(Clone, Copy)]`.

Rust Playground [Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5ac3c8b5abfb3dae12f4d024e8a834e7)

Comment: This works! Can you please throw some more insights on how this works? Where does the move happen?

Comment: I think because `game` is `&B` the "move" happens precisely when you do `game.result`.  A quick search turned up [a similar question](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnrust/comments/sc7fnn/where_does_this_shared_reference_come_from) on r/learnrust.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to refactor the program to only print what is actually needed:

```
…
fn main() {
    let game: B = B { result: A::Won };
        print_result(game.result);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=da5981a3e8691163b7ad9fcac1ce1fa7)